# Are there any risk in serving static assets via compressed SSL protocol from 3rd party domain?

Tags: web-application, tls, appsec, http, openssl

e.g.

```
curl -v -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip' 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Colors.js/1.2.2/colors.min.js'
```

As you can see, result is gzipped.

My assumption is since they are serving from 3rd party domain, it is safe for me. I only need to disable when it is served from my own domain, right?

Comment: Should be safe since the file content isn't secret. CRIME only broke confidentiality, not authenticity.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First note that you are *not* using SSL-level compression, but HTTP-level compression: there is a HTTP header which describes the mode of compression. The compression is applied to the HTTP response *body* only, i.e. the `colors.min.js` file, at the exclusion of anything else, in particular HTTP cookies or other such values.

Compression is unsafe when applied on *secret values* and the attacker has the possibility to get *many examples* of compressed data with the same secret repeated in all of them, but also with variants. In particular when the attacker gets to insert data *chosen by him* within the data sequence that is compressed.

In the case you show, there is no secret data at all; the data sequence that is compressed is a completely public piece of Javascript. Compression is abused into attacks by its ability to leak information about data *contents* through the data *length* (and the *length* is not protected by any subsequent encryption). If the source data is completely public, then there is no information to leak, and therefore no attack.

(Though `colors.min.js` is public, you still want to get over HTTPS, not for *confidentiality* but for *integrity*: you want to prevent active attackers from changing the Javascript code on the fly.)

Even if the compressed data was not public, a static file could still be served with compression, because compression is deterministic and would yield the exact same sequence of bytes every time, so, in particular, always the same length -- nothing to learn for the attacker.

Comment: Thanks, I am a little bit confused by SSL compression & HTTP compression, 1. are there any example of public site using SSL compression? Can it be checked via curl? 2. I assume HTTP compression also hurt security if the data is secret, right?

Comment: SSL compression has been mostly deactivated everywhere in the aftermath of the CRIME attack. I don't think `curl` would show it; it is very internal to the SSL library. `openssl s_client` would tell you if the server allows compression, but since modern Web browsers don't support it anymore, it won't be used in practice.

Comment: HTTP-level compression _can_ hurt when that which is compressed contains both secret data and attacker-chosen data, in the same response body. Apparently this can happen in some web site; so-called "BREACH attack" seems to be a demonstration of such a thing. This depends on the Web site and its structure. Generally, "static pages" can be safely compressed, because, by being static, they won't include attacker-chosen data.

Comment: so I think most SSL compression is turned off by default in most server, but HTTP compression (via SSL) is still very popular, so we should also disable it as well?

Comment: You can keep compression for everything which is not in SSL. For things which are protected by SSL, you can safely keep compression for static pages; for anything generated dynamically, well... it depends. So the _generic_ safe thing is to disable HTTP-level compression for all dynamic pages served over SSL.

Comment: Thanks, so can I say Yahoo seems to have problem as them return gzip content over SSL for their login page? curl -I -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip'  'https://login.yahoo.com/config/login'

Comment: They have a _potential_ problem. The Devil is in the details. See [this site](http://breachattack.com/): to abuse HTTP compression into an attack, the site must offer a page which contains a secret that the attacker is after, _and_ reflects some data that the attacker can choose. This may or may not apply to Yahoo's login page.